# Why is the browser not setting cookies after an AJAX request returns?

Tags: ajax, cookies

I am making an ajax request using $.ajax.  The response has the `Set-Cookie` header set (I've verified this in the Chrome dev tools).  However, the browser does *not* set the cookie after receiving the response!  When I navigate to another page within my domain, the cookie is not sent.  (Note: I'm not doing any cross-domain ajax requests; the request is in the same domain as the document.)

What am I missing?

**EDIT**: Here is the code for my ajax request:

```
$.post('/user/login', JSON.stringify(data));
```

Here is the request, as shown by the Chrome dev tools:

```
Request URL:https://192.168.1.154:3000/user/login
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers:
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:35
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
DNT:1
Host:192.168.1.154:3000
Origin:https://192.168.1.154:3000
Referer:https://192.168.1.154:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Form Data:
{"UserId":"blah","Password":"blah"}:
```

Response:

```
Response Headers:
Content-Length:15
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date:Sun, 16 Mar 2014 03:25:24 GMT
Set-Cookie:SessionId=MTM5NDk0MDMyNHxEdi1CQkFFQ180SUFBUkFCRUFBQVRfLUNBQUVHYzNSeWFXNW5EQXNBQ1ZObGMzTnBiMjVKWkFaemRISnBibWNNTGdBc1ZFcDNlU3RKVFdKSGIzQlNXRkkwVjJGNFJ6TlRVSHA0U0ZJd01XRktjMDF1Y1c1b2FGWXJORzV4V1QwPXwWf1tz-2Fy_Y4I6fypCzkMJyYxhgM3LjVHGAlKyrilRg==; HttpOnly
```

Comment: So this might be an old thread, but I stumbled upon it looking for something else and I noticed that your request had `DNT: 1` in the header. If I recall, this is Do Not Track and the browsers is requesting to not allow cookies to be set.

Comment: If you're having this issue with Apollo, check out [this section](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/authentication.html) of their documentation

Answer (score 81, accepted):

OK, so I finally figured out the problem.  It turns out that setting the `Path` option is important when sending cookies in an AJAX request.  If you set `Path=/`, e.g.:

```
Set-Cookie:SessionId=foo; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

...then the browser will set the cookie when you navigate to a different page.  Without setting `Path`, the browser uses the "default" path.  Apparently, the default path for a cookie set by an AJAX request is different from the default path used when you navigate to a page directly. I'm using Go/Martini, so on the server-side I do this:

```
session.Options(session.Options{HttpOnly: true, Path:"/"})
```

I'd guess that Python/Ruby/etc. have a similar mechanism for setting `Path`.

See also: [cookies problem in PHP and AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353782/cookies-problem-in-php-and-ajax)

Comment: Dayum, that was useful! In java (using the servlet API) : `cookie.setPath("/");`

Comment: Finally!! Two of us have spent a day trying to figure out why our CORS+AJAX cookies weren't working!

Comment: Thanks, I spent a few hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: Spent some time looking for a solution and adding Path to the cookie was it

Answer (score 69):

@atomkirk's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39233628/1175496) didn't apply to me because

1. I don't use the `fetch` API
2. I was making *cross-site* requests (i.e. CORS)

**NOTE:** If your server is **using `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` (aka "all origins"/"wildcard origins")**, you may not be able to send credentials (see below).

## Setting `withCredentials`/`credentials` in browser/client request

**As for the `fetch` API; CORS requests will [need `{credentials:'include'}`](https://github.com/github/fetch#sending-cookies) for both sending & receiving cookies**

> For CORS requests, use the "include" value to allow **sending**
> credentials to other domains:
>
> ```
> fetch('https://example.com:1234/users', {   
>             credentials: 'include' 
> })
> ```
>
> ... To opt into **accepting** cookies from the server, you must use the credentials option.

---

**`{credentials:'include'}` is equivalent to [`xhr.withCredentials=true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials)**

[In fact, check`fetch` polyfill code (a Javascript implementation)](https://github.com/github/fetch/blob/master/fetch.js#L565)

> ```
> if (request.credentials === 'include') {
>       xhr.withCredentials = true
>  }
> ```

As @haneSmitter says in the comments, if `fetch` is implemented natively by your browser, you don't need a Javascript polyfill, so use the appropriate value for fetch `credentials` property. `fetch` allows three values for { credentials:'...' } configuration ( "omit", "same-origin", or "include"), whereas xhr is only a boolean (two values: true or false). Read more at the [fetch spec here](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-credentials-mode)

---

**If you're using jQuery, you [can set withCredentials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26014294/1175496) (remember to use `crossDomain: true`) using `$.ajaxSetup(...)`**

> ```
> $.ajaxSetup({
>              crossDomain: true,
>              xhrFields: {
>                  withCredentials: true
>              }
>          });
> ```

---

**If you're using AngularJS, the [`$http` service config arg](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-arguments) accepts a `withCredentials` property:**

> ```
> $http({
>     withCredentials: true
> });
> ```

---

**If you're using Angular (Angular IO), the [`common.http.HttpRequest` service options arg](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#withCredentials) accepts a `withCredentials` property:**

> ```
> this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, {
>     withCredentials: true
> });
> ```

---

**As for the request, when `xhr.withCredentials=true`; the Cookie header is sent**

Before I changed `xhr.withCredentials=true`

1. I could see Set-Cookie name & value in the response, but Chrome's "Application" tab in the Developer Tools showed me the name and an **empty value**
2. Subsequent requests **did not send** a `Cookie` request header.

After the change `xhr.withCredentials=true`

1. I **could see** the cookie's **name** and the cookie's **value** in the Chrome's "Application" tab (a value consistent with the Set-Cookie header).
2. Subsequent requests **did** send a `Cookie` request header with the same value, so my server treated me as "authenticated"

---

## Setting `Access-Control...` headers in server response

**As for the response, if your request is a cross-site request, the server **will need certain `Access-Control...` headers****

For example, I configured my server to return these headers:

- Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
- Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://{your-origin}:{your-port}

Until I made this server-side change to the response headers, Chrome logged errors in the console like

> Failed to load `https://{saml-domain}/saml-authn`: Redirect from `https://{saml-domain}/saml-redirect` has been blocked by CORS policy:
>
> The value of the `'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'` header in the response is `''` which must be `'true'` when the request's credentials mode is `'include'`. Origin `https://{your-domain}` is therefore not allowed access.
>
> The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

After making this Access-* header change, Chrome did not log errors; the browser let me check the authenticated responses for all subsequent requests.

## Can't use wildcard/asterisk `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`, use dynamic value based on request

Using `withCredentials` **and** setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` (aka wildcard, allowing "all origins") **won't work**. As seen in the comments and [described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials) (thanks to @ChandanBhattad). You might see this error:

> The CORS request was attempted with the credentials flag set, but the server is configured using the wildcard ("*") as the value of Access-Control-Allow-Origin, which doesn't allow the use of credentials.

Therefore if you control the server and you want to allow cross-origin requests from *any* origin, you must **dynamically decide the response value based on the request origin**, or as [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin):

> If the server supports clients from multiple origins, it must return the origin **for the specific client making the request.**

For example, your server should inspect the request, if the request comes from `http://www.example.com`, your response headers should include:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com
Vary: Origin
```

Note the use of the `Vary` response header, which MDN says:

> indicates to browsers that server responses can differ based on the value of the Origin request header.

How to change your server response headers depends on your server technology.

- Some example .NET WebAPI / .NET Core resources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959114/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-update-a-list-of-allowed-origins-in-web-api-cors), [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/manage-cors-policy-dynamically/), and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3c3TkULcLR8)
- Some Node.js express examples [here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#configuring-cors-w-dynamic-origin)
- Some Python django examples [here](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers#signals) and [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57429117/how-to-dynamically-populate-cors-origin-whitelist-from-the-database-with-django)
- etc...

Comment: Really helped me a lot. Works :D

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. Worked for me.

Comment: `for both sending & RECEIVING cookies`
That did help.

Comment: This seems to be the right answer. Processed user authentication in ajax POST request, but cookie wasn't set. Interestingly this problem occured only on mobile browsers, on desktop not. xhrFields: { withCredentials: true } parameter apparently fixed the issue. Too bad I found this answer after fixing the problem, it was driving me crazy for a few days.

Comment: Sendering and RECEIVING.. for real. I was POSTing to my login endpoint with { withCredentials: false } set and spent 4+ hours trying to figure out why the cookies we not being set.

Comment: Thank you. I was in the same situation as you, using cross-site cookies (my backend is running in a host and the frontend in another host). I had everything in place, except that I wasn't using the withCredentials flag in the login request, only in subsequent requests. Once I used it in the login request (had to configure my CORS policies in the right way, as it doesn't like when allowed origins is *), it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't seem to work if I have set "access-control-allow-origin:*" .
Basically - "credentials": "include" is not allowed when access-control-allow-origin is set to * ?

Comment: Good point from @ChandanBhattad - this approach won't work if you allow *all* origins, as [described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials): "The CORS request was attempted with the credentials flag set, but the server is configured using the wildcard ("*") as the value of Access-Control-Allow-Origin, which doesn't allow the use of credentials."

Comment: yeah. I had a use case where i wanted to set it for any origin. as a workaround - I am now setting access-control-allow-origin header value to the request origin :)

Comment: That is a nice solution, I used the same "dynamic" approach; it requires the server to inspect the request, and repeat the *request's origin*, as the Access-Control-Allow-origin value in the response, right? So if request came from "a", it would allow origin "a", etc... Some folks may not have a server "smart enough" to do that.

Comment: `{credentials:'include'}` just sets `xhr.withCredentials=true`. I find this confusing since **fetch** API in browsers was not built on top of **xhr**.

Comment: @haneSmitter I think  `fetch(...,{credentials:'include'})` is *almost equivalent* to `xhr.withCredentials=true`, but I don't think it's correct to say the former "just sets" the latter...  `fetch` is a different specification than `xhr`, a different implementation. [`fetch` allows **three values** for `{ credentials:'...' }`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-credentials-mode) configuration ( "omit", "same-origin", or "include"), whereas `xhr` is only a boolean (**two values**: true or false). Maybe this is confusing, but the specs clarify the difference in behavior.

Comment: @haneSmitter Now I see what you mean! I myself wrote "{credentials:'include'} just sets xhr.withCredentials=true". You're right, that's confusing, fetch is a browser API, I was referring to the fetch *polyfill* (Javascript-based replacement for browsers that did not support fetch). I'll clarify my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 46):

If you're using the new `fetch` API, you can try including `credentials`:

```
fetch('/users', {
  credentials: 'same-origin'
})
```

That's what fixed it for me.

In particular, using the polyfill: https://github.com/github/fetch#sending-cookies

Comment: Im with @jag on this one!! I just spent 4 hours trying to login via ajax using passport.js... total mystery until I hit on the network response returning the cookie. It simply wouldn't save. Your solution fixed it. Cheers

Comment: After adding credentials and path in the set-cookie response, it works for me

Comment: Note: if your api lives on another domain, you'll need to use `credentials: 'include'`. Also, if you're having this issue with apollo, check out [this section](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/authentication.html) of their docs.

Answer (score 2):

This may help somebody randomly falling across this question.

I found forcing a URL with https:// rather than http:// even though the server hasn't got a certificate and Chrome complains will fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the cookie size exceeded 4096 bytes (Google Chrome). I had a dynamic cookie payload that would increase in size.

Browsers will ignore the `set-cookie` response header if the cookie exceeds the browsers limit, and it will not set the cookie.

[See here](http://browsercookielimits.squawky.net/) for cookie size limits per browser.

I know this isn't the solution, but this was my issue, and I hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is, when setting the cookie options from the server side, set `sameSite=none` and `secure=true` and `domain=yourdomain`

The browser automatically block the cookie if these options are not set when using fetch api