# IdentityServer4 Host with SPA front end

Tags: asp.net-core, single-page-application, identityserver4

I'm trying to use identity server 4 as a SSO site with a front-end written as an SPA (framework not important)

The Example project uses MVC, which when the user logs in the page posts to a controller that redirects the browser to the return URL.

I'm having trouble modifying this flow to work in a more AJAX fashion. Firstly I want to be able to submit the username/password to an API controller so that I can get back validation errors etc without doing a page refresh. Given a successful login I then need to redirect the browser to the returnUrl, but I cannot get this to work and the callback url returns the user back to the login page again rather than redirecting to the client app logged in.

This is what my login endpoint looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/identity/login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model)
{
    // check credentials in model etc
    await _eventsService.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(model.Email, subjectId, model.Email));
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(subjectId, model.Email, new AuthenticationProperties());
    return Ok();
}
```

And simple form as a front-end, this is hosted on a static html page:

```
<form>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" />

    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" />

    <button onclick="login()" type="submit">Log me in</button>
</form>
<script>
    var email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
    var password = document.querySelector('#password').value;
    var returnUrl = unescape(window.location.search.replace('?returnUrl=', ''));
    fetch('/api/identity/login', {
            body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }),
            method: 'POST'
    }).then(() => {
        var returnUrl = unescape(window.location.search.replace('?returnUrl=', ''));
        window.location = window.location.origin + returnUrl;
    })
</script>
```

On a 200 response I use javascript to redirect the browser to the returnUrl.

I'm not sure what I'm missing to get this to work. Do I need to sign the user in and redirect all in one call?

I am modifying an existing example app here which does work with the direct post/redirect method as expected, so both host and client config is unchanged: https://github.com/BenjaminAbt/Samples.AspNetCore-IdentityServer4

Comment: You need to provide more code.  Please show what you have already done, not what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi @Brad, I have included some more code. Have I explained the problem clearly enough?

Comment: Did you set your routing as `path: ' ', component: LoginComponent` ?

Comment: @k11k2 not sure what you mean, since I'm serving a static page for the login ui at the root of the site I have set this in Startup.cs: 

            `services.AddIdentityServer(options => {
                    options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/";
                })`

Comment: @dpix, just out of interest, how would you handle scenarios of partial login with the ajax approach here? Like 2FA, consent, forced password reset or anything that might be required before signing in?

Comment: @danijels in this simplified example I am always redirecting to the return url. Based on the response from the login ajax call you would need to handle the response appropriately to show an extra consent form (2fa or password reset). On the backend you need to make sure you are not issuing any tokens or actually logging the user in until they have completed everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating some logs and watching the requests a little more carefully I realised that the login response from the AJAX request was not setting the authentication cookie on the browser.

Setting the `credentials` option in the fetch request to `'same-origin'` fixed the issue

thanks to this stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39233628