# How to dynamically populate CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST from the database with django-cors-headers?

Tags: python, django

I am writing a django application where I have a model called `Website` which contains websites of people. I only allow people who have their websites in my database to use my Django REST API. I am using the `django-cors-headers` package to whitelist the domains of people: https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers.

`CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` variable in settings.py allows me to white list domains as shown in https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers#cors_origin_whitelist

The problem is that I have to query my models to get the website domains, append them to a list and then put that list into `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST`. But I can't do that in settings.py because models are loaded after the app starts and settings.py is the one that starts the app.

Does anyone know a way around that? Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will you restart your web server every time you need to add a new website?

Comment: You should use the signal provided for exactly this use case, see the [docs](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers#signals)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`django-cors-headers` has a signal that allows you to decide whether or not to allow the `request` to pass. The [docs](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers#signals) show exactly your use case.

Note that `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` is also checked by the cors middleware (the signal response doesn't *replace* the white list), so you can have both: a static whitelist + a dynamic whitelist that depends on the `request`. You don't need to check the static whitelist in your signal handler.

Comment: Thanks! How dumb of me to not see that.

Answer (score 1):

`django-cors-headers` also has a setting `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES`, which comes in handy if your allowed origins can be written as a regex / regular expression.

For example, you could use this to allow wildcard subdomains:

```py
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES = [
    r"^https://\w+\.example\.com$",
]
```