# AngularJS $http POST request

Tags: angularjs, json, cookies

When I'm making POST request with headers as `content-type: application/JSON` headers don't set a cookie in Request Headers. But when I change the headers as `content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` headers set a cookie in Request Headers. 
Server accepts `application/JSON` format.
Also, I have already given `with-credentials: true` on the client side.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Though the code is not available, I assume that setting the path parameter of the cookie will do the trick for you. The following may help:

[cookies problem in PHP and AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353782/cookies-problem-in-php-and-ajax)

[Why is the browser not setting cookies after an AJAX request returns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432616/why-is-the-browser-not-setting-cookies-after-an-ajax-request-returns)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Yes preference is right. But this answer is based on assumption of the essential part as that part of the code is not provided.